# sending a json and an audio file to specific socketId from my app over Socket.io websocket

Tags: android, json, performance, audio, socket.io

I am trying to set up a chat functionality for my app and I am wondering about the best way to do it.

here is what I am envisioning so far:

the user decides and selects with whom he wants to communicate, then he records an audio message that is saved as a file and emits it to the websocket.

Since the android implementation of Socket.IO doesn't include the `.to(socketId)` method I need to pass the id of the intended receiver of the message (along with some other message relevant data) inside a JSON that the server can then be read in order to emit the message using the appropriate `.to(socketId)` call. As I want to send both text and audio I am converting my audio file to `byte[] byteArrayOfAudio` and then using `new String(byteArrayOfAudio)` to convert it to a String. I then add this sting to the JSON and that the actual text i send it over to the websocket.

the server reads the message and finds the connection ID  (socketId) matching the user ID of the receiver. and then forwards the message to the appropriate receiver. the receiver decodes the json gets the audio string, converts it to byte[], then converts that back to the appropriate audio format and then the receiver can play it.

My questions are:

- is this best practice?
- is there any way to tell the server directly from android what socketId the messege is to be forwarded to? is there any potentially costly processing overhead for the server for having to constantly read say 50 000 character JSON objects just to get the receivers ID?
- I know that stringifying a file increases its size, is there any better way of doing this?

the audio files are rather small (up to 50kb) and, if the gains are not significant, I would prefer for the audio file and related text data to be sent in one `.emit()`

any helpful infromation will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you avoid sending audio using json ... when using websockets its entirely up to you to define the protocol between client and server ... every websocket message must be either a text message or a binary message ... send audio using the binary message type not wrapped in json

when you send each audio buffer send it alone with no other attributes ... once sent this way over on receiving side test incoming websocket message for type and treat the binary message separately from the text message traffic

To uniquely identify the sender of this binary traffic you could tag the metadata inside this buffer with some sender id ...  alternatively on sender side you could create a hash of the binary audio buffer to act as a unique identifier of that buffer then send a json message with this hash and a sender id tag so receiver side knows its coming and can uniquely match that next binary message with the sender

Comment: ok this is a helpful idea but how will the server know to whom to forward the message. the server will be a plattform for users to chat with each other via audio message. many users will chat amongst each other at the same time. with the json I can write the sender and receiver IDs inside the json but if I send a standalone binary how does the server know to whom it is addressed?

Comment: keep in mind that the same user could be receiving multiple audio messages at the same time from various different other users and on arrival I would have to know how to assign this binary data to each of my open communication lines. thinking about it just now i have wondered if this could be achieved with hash but i ask myself what real gains I am looking at from doing this. encoding the audio with base64 is adding 33% file size to the payload, is this really that bad.

Comment: is the idea with the file hashes the right way to do this? this would mean id have to cache the hash of a file corresponding to a json msg on the server so i can use it to forward the byte arry to the right socketId, right?